# Tangents and Normals of a circle

Tags: geometry

If two tangents are drawn to a circle with any arbitrary angle between them , is it necessary that the normals to these tangents will always intersect at the centre of the circle ? Because in one of the solved examples that I went through , the combined equation for the pair normals of a circle was given. Then in my book , they isolated the individual equation for the normals and found out the point of intersection which they called as the center of the circle.

Comment: Yes. Draw a diagram and you will very clearly see why.

Comment: @Landuros Thank you. So does it mean that the normal to tangent drawn at any point to a circle is always the radius of the circle ?

Comment: Yes, if the normal terminates at the centre of the circle.

Comment: @Landuros okay thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: A "key-figure" for understanding it can be found here : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945796)